# ASP.NET 5: What is the recommended approach to catch and log all unhandled exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm building an api app.
In the old ASP.NET there was Application_Error() to catch all unhandled exceptions

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    _logger.FatalException("Fatal error.", exception);
}
```

What should be used in ASP.NET 5?

Comment: There is a nice explanation of this on SO. Use ILoggerProvider and ILogger from the namespace Microsoft.Framework.Logging. The details can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385889/global-exception-handling-in-asp-net-5. The github also have sample for same. https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples/ExceptionHandlerSample

Comment: the answer there is a bit outdated

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add a custom filter. This is how it could be done:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new MyExceptionFilter()));
}
```

Now the custom filter should derive from IExceptionFilter:

```
public class MyExceptionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't catch exceptions during Startup.Configuration()

Comment: Have you been able to find a better way of doing this like "Application_Error" on asp. net 4