# How to add HttpContext to enrich un-handled exception logs?

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-2.0, error-logging, serilog

I have setup Serilog to log to MSSql using:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Async(x => x.MSSqlServer(logConntectionString, tableName, LogEventLevel.Warning, autoCreateSqlTable: false, columnOptions: columnOptions))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Additionally I have added added a SerilogMiddleware in the pipeline that successfully adds `LogContext` from the `HttpContext`.

In a test controller, I have these 2 test methods:

```cs
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("test")]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        try
        {
            string[] sar = new string[0];                
            var errorgenerator = sar[2]; // Trigger exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Caught Exception");
            return StatusCode(500, "Custom 500 Error");
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("test2")]
    public IActionResult Get2() {

        string[] sar = new string[0];
        var errorgenerator = sar[2];// Trigger exception

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The first method is not DRY, and so I would like to handle global/uncaught exceptions such as method 2.

What I have [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626310/asp-net-5-what-is-the-recommended-approach-to-catch-and-log-all-unhandled-excep) is:

```cs
public class GloablExceptionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{    
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;  //  This does not appear to have the actual HttpContext

        Log.Error(context.Exception, "Unhandled Exception");
    }
}
```

Problem is, my middleware that otherwise worked no longer does.. It does not edit the response body, etc...  Further, when I access ExceptionContext's `context.HttpContext`, it does not contain the actual HttpContext when triggered from inside a controller method such as above.

1. How do I inject or share HttpContext and or LogContext with this Filter?
2. If thats not possible, how do I accomplish logging exceptions, while being DRY, *and* having context when its available?

**Update 1: Current Middleware**

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();            

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Logging Middleware is just after Authentication, to have access to 
    // user IsAuthorized, claims, etc..
    app.UseMiddleware<SerilogMiddleware>();

    app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In the middleware itself:

```cs
public class SerilogMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SerilogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (next == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
      // Do logging stuff with Request..
       await _next(httpContext);
      // Do logging stuff with Response but..
      // This point is never reached, when exception is unhandled.
    }
}
```

Comment: You can consider using an actual middleware placed early in the pipeline which has direct access to the htttp context as apposed to a filer which enters the pipeline much later.

Comment: Found an example in an answer I gave https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791487/5233410

Comment: [@Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) - I added the middleware code and the order its injected to demonstrate.  I didn't want the question to be overly broad, or too narrow to my use for that matter.

Comment: Based on code snippet you are not catching the exception when you pass the context down the pipeline. If you do not catch the exception then it wont reach your code.

Comment: You Try/Catch the `await _next(httpContext)` in the middleware -  I see; thank you!  Make an answer and I will mark it if you wish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on code snippet you are not catching the exception when you pass the context down the pipeline.

If you do not catch/handle the exception within the middleware then it wont reach your code after calling down stream.

```cs
public class SerilogMiddleware {
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SerilogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        if (next == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) {
        // Do logging stuff with Request..
        try {
            await _next(httpContext);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            try {
                //Do exception specific logging

                // if you don't want to rethrow the original exception
                // then call return:
                // return;
            } catch (Exception loggingException) {
                //custom
            }

            // Otherwise re -throw the original exception
            throw;
        }
        // Do logging stuff with Response      
    }
}
```

The above will re-throw the original error after logging it so that the other handler in the pipeline will catch it and do the out of the box handling.